# Expo CLI - Error: Cannot find module '/home/expo/workingdir/build/.yarn/releases/yarn-1.22.19.cjs'

Tags: react-native, expo, yarnpkg

I currently have an ejected Expo 46.0.9 react-native app. The app lives under a shared nx monorepo (although it isn't connected as one through its project.json)

I've been using the following command successfully to send my Expo app to the CLI

```
eas build --profile preview --platform android
eas build --profile preview --platform ios
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Running "yarn install" in /home/expo/workingdir/build/apps/react-native-app directory

[stderr] 
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988

[stderr] 
  throw err;

[stderr] 
  ^

[stderr] 

[stderr] 
Error: Cannot find module '/home/expo/workingdir/build/.yarn/releases/yarn-1.22.19.cjs'

[stderr] 
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)

[stderr] 
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:833:27)

[stderr] 
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)

[stderr] 
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47 {

[stderr] 
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

[stderr] 
  requireStack: []

[stderr] 
}

yarn exited with non-zero code: 1
```

It seems it's a problem with Yarn.

But I don't know what it is. I'm currently using Yarn V1.22

Answer (score 0):

The problem was outside of Expo and react-native.

We recently included a NextJS project that excluded the `.yarn` folder.

gitignore:

```
# Omitted for brevity
/generated
**/generated

# Coverage directory used by tools like istanbul
coverage
**/coverage

# Next.js
.next
```

What was strange was that it was reading it from the root of the monorepo

[image]

So the fix was to tell it not to exclude the folders as mentioned in the [yarn configuration](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/qa) (even though we were using yarn v1):

```
.yarn/*
!.yarn/cache
!.yarn/patches
!.yarn/plugins
!.yarn/releases
!.yarn/sdks
!.yarn/versions
```